# Two mat-errors for different validators

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in which I'm adding locations and require Name, Status, Latitude and Longitude fields. I have used custom pattern validation for latitude and longitude and have used them to show error messages as below-

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" style="display: block;">
            <mat-label>Latitude</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="lat" matInput placeholder="Enter Latitude">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>location_on</mat-icon>
            <mat-hint>Mandatory Field</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="editLocationForm.controls.lat.errors?.required && editLocationForm.controls.lat.dirty">
              Latitude is Required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="editLocationForm.controls.lat.errors?.pattern && editLocationForm.controls.lat.touched">
              Latitude should be in correct format</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

I'm able to see both the error messages as per whenever the conditions become true. I'm trying to do the same for my City Name with Required and MinLength Validators as below-

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" style="display: block;">
            <mat-label>Location Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter City Name">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>location_on</mat-icon>
            <mat-hint>Mandatory Field</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="editLocationForm.controls.name.errors?.required && editLocationForm.controls.name.dirty">
              Location Name is Required</mat-error>
            <mat-error
              *ngIf="editLocationForm.controls.name.errors?.minLength && editLocationForm.controls.name.touched">
              Location Name should have min. 4 characters</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

My form field gets red but ***I don't see error message when the name is less than 4 characters***. Here's how I am initializing my form -

```
this.editLocationForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        id: [''],
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
        status: ['', Validators.required],
        lat: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/)]],
        lon: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/)]]
      }
    )
```

Any reason why I'm not able to see the error message for city name?

Answer (score 0):

*editLocationForm.controls.name.errors?.minLength* should be written as *editLocationForm.controls.name.errors?.***minlength*** with a small 'L'.

Just found out about this.